# Creating master agent and sub agent using snmp4j-agentx

Tags: snmp, agent, snmp4j

I am doing internship in a company. I have been asked to find a way to implement snmp agents in one of their systems using java. I tried to find a free MIB compiler for java but failed. Hence I am trying to do that using SNMP4J-agentX library (because they specifically said they need master and sub agents). I have never worked with it before so I am having difficulty trying to implement it. There is a sample master agent and sub agent in the library package. I dont understand how i can modify it to include variables from my own mib file. Or if anyone have a simpler sample master agent or sub agent code, it would be very helpful if you can share it. I am only a little familiar with the internal working of an agent. So please if anyone can help please do so from a relatively basic level.
Many thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding your own MIB objects (so called ManagedObjects) to your SNMP agent with SNMP4J-AgentX works in the same way as for SNMP4J-Agent. The only exception from this are AgentX shared tables, but these are advanced concepts you generally do not need when you start using AgentX/SNMP.

Thus, I recommend reading the [SNMP4J-Agent-Instrumentation-Guide.pdf](http://www.snmp4j.org/SNMP4J-Agent-1.4-InstrumentationGuide.pdf) to learn how MIB objects are registered and instrumentated based on your requirements.